# What is the most cost-efficient solution when door keys do not fit ignition?

Tags: ignition, locks, key, fob

I know similar questions have been asked but I'm specifically looking for the most cost efficient way to solve the following problem. I have a 2006 Lexus RX400h for which the physical door key does not fit the lock cylinder of the door (but it does start the car). I open the car door with the key fob. I bought the car this way so I don't know the exact backstory.

The fact that my physical car key does not open the door lock cylinder does not usually bother me. But when the battery dies, I am unable to get into my own car. So I'd like to resolve this situation. After speaking with some folks, I believe the previous owners probably changed the ignition cylinder without changing the door locks. Then they just reprogrammed the key fob to open the door and to start the car.

My current thinking is the following: It seems like changing the door lock cylinder is probably more expensive than changing the ignition cylinder back to factory specs and then getting a factory key and program that key to open and start the car.

I could get all of this done with my local Lexus dealership. But knowing dealerships, I am certain that this will be expensive. I also feel like I cannot get reliable information from the dealership, a mechanic, or a locksmith because all of them have an interest in selling me their services.

So now my question is what would be the least expensive way to deal with this?

Comment: What I did for my daughter with the same situation (09 Honda Fit - Door was replaced without the original lock getting placed ... there's a question on here about it somewhere), was to hook heavy gauge wires directly to her battery with two weatherproof posts inside the wheel well on the driver's side. If the battery in the car goes dead, she can hook a small 12v source up to the posts and get enough juice to unlock the door and thus the hood to give the car a boost.

Comment: Frame challenge: Buy a decent battery that doesn't keep going dead / Stop leaving your lights on.

Comment: @Valorum the battery in his _fob_, not in his car.

Comment: @AdamBarnes - I've read it twice. Where does it say that?

Comment: @AdamBarnes - Also, frame challenge #2, spend 50p on a new battery and tape it to the underside of the bumper..

Comment: @Valorum The battery dying in a car is a failure state.  The battery dying in the fob is expected.  Read as a native, he's not talking about his car battery.  I don't know of a single person who sellotapes CR2032s to their car.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'm curious why heavy gauge wires as a permanent fixture when the 12v source is "small" - was the intention that the car could be boosted via the wheel well?

Comment: @CaiusJard - When I say "heavy gauge" wires, I'm suggesting something like a 14-16 gauge on each the + and - leads. The idea is to give the car enough juice to open the locks via the fob versus using it to boost the car and start it. I wouldn't use something like a 22 gauge wire or the like. I'm just suggesting something which is a little heavier so you don't have any issues. And by "small", I'm talking something like a 12vdc battery you'd find in a battery backup (UPS) or used for a garage door opener. It's much bigger than a D-cell, but quite a bit smaller than a car battery.

Comment: It's easier to tie a wire to the release latch on the hood and tie the other end to the bottom of the radiator so if you lock it closed you can just reach under and pull the string to pop the hood. Then a small 12v battery charger or battery will give you enough juice for the locks to open.

Comment: @CaiusJard the (initial) current may be rather large if the battery is so low it can't operate the central locking, even from a fairly small battery, which would run down pretty quickly. You could melt small wires

Comment: Minor note that it might also be worth considering carrying a spare battery attached to the fob, in something like one of those ["holds coins for the parking meter" fobs](https://www.ebay.com/itm/A/153231708356)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Is there a fuse in the wires you rigged directly to the battery?  If not, I think that's worth a question here to ask the experts if that's safe (and if not, how to make it safe).  The failure state I'm worried about is the positive wire's insulation getting worn, the wire shorting to chassis, and then the wire getting really hot and possibly starting a fire.

Comment: @WayneConrad - There's no fuse and one isn't needed. Reason being is, this is a battery to battery hookup. While not as much amperage as if you were boosting your battery, it's the same exact process. You don't have a fuse when you boost/jump from one car to another, you don't need one here. Agree on the wire shorting, but if you run the wire correctly, there's no worry of this either.

Comment: @Valorum - Neither situation you state was what happened to my daughter. Her stock radio (navigation unit) decided it would start up spontaneously and run continuously even with the ignition off, which killed the battery. Since the main battery in the car is relatively small (480CCA - IIRC), there's not a lot of reserve in it, which when there is a constant draw, it kills it pretty quickly. My point being, other things can cause the battery to die besides operator error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Being a auto locksmith, I can 100% recommend that you have your door lock rekeyed to match your current ignition key. Cost will depend on location and if you remove the the lock yourself and take it to a shop or if you call a reputable mobile smith to come out. I charge about $90 for mobile service and a simple rekey like this.

The lock is simple to remove, there is a set screw on the side of door frame you undo and the lock pulls out to remove. I guess a shop would charge about $50.

Rekeying ignition is not as easy because these are somewhat sealed units and need a little drilling to open up so it will cost more. I'd say more along the lines of $100 shop/ $200 mobile. PLUS you will need to have a new case cut to move transponder in or new key programmed all together to match back to the ignition which will be in addition to the ignition rekey cost.

Dealer has no idea how to rekey anything. They will just replace stuff. I wouldn't bother with them in this case.

Its also possible your door lock is just seized up. It is very common on lexus locks around those years. Bad grease that dries up. Spray a healthy bit of wd40 in there and work your key in and out some. If still does not work take the lock out and spray MORE wd40 in the big drain hole underneath the lock while putting your key in and out.

Comment: Are your prices linked to your location or valid across the world?

Comment: Its about the norm for my region and likely close all around the US.  But it will vary  depending on location. As for  the question itself, The cheapest way to achieve what they are asking  will be to rekey the door lock regardless or location.

Comment: "Its also possible your door lock is just seized up." I second that.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with this.  Ignition hard, door easy. Just remove the door lock and walk it into a retail locksmith.

Comment: Having replaced several door locks in my lifetime do to botched thefts etc, My first instinct as well was that getting a new door lock would be much easier than a new ignition.

Answer (score 2):

Your *cheapest* option might be to leave everything keyed the way that it is and simply have separate keys for the door and for the ignition.  You'd have to get a key made for the door, but that should be cheaper than rekeying the lock.  This is what I do with my house, which has two different locks on different doors.  One of those keys only gets used on very rare occasions, similar to OP's situation, so it's not a lot of extra hassle.  However, this option would get extremely annoying if this was your primary way of unlocking the door.

Comment: This is another option, yes. Still, my charge would be the same or cheaper for a rekey vrs a (all keys lost) replacement key on this one. Its basically a simple service call/flat price to cover the time for 1 basic job on this particular keyway either way you look at it. Most walk-in shops are going to be the same as me just without a extra charge for coming too you. You *may* give a smith the keycode from the door lock and sweet talk them a bit to get a discount on a basic "code cut key" but I wouldn't count on it being much cheaper on this key system.